# JSON Parsing in iOS5.1

Tags: json, ios5

What is the best way to parse this JSON String in iOS 5.1 - Is it best practice to use native JSON parsing or something like RestKit is better ?

```
[{"key":"value", "key2":"value2"},{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}]
```

I am using this code but all I get is  values back

```
query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);

return results;
```

Comment: What do you mean you get values back, isn't that good? can you please include the input JSON data and whats returned from `JSONObjectWithData` (or what error you get).

Comment: I only get back a "NULL" when I run the code..

Comment: Also it looks like your escaping the whole URL when you probably should only escape the key and values in the query. Check if you actually get any jsonData from the server, i would guess jsonData is nil.

Comment: jsonData is not nil - its getting back correct values

Comment: So how does the data in jsonData look? have you tried to run it thru a JSON-linter?

Comment: I just tried with JsonKit instead and I still cant figure it out - the JSON is valid I have verified with JSON-linter already

Comment: Have you really verified that `query` is a valid working URL? that is: used `NSLog(@"query=%@", query);` or a breakpoint and then copy paste the URL into a browser and see that you actually get anything.

Comment: yes pretty sure of that one...the same URL works in RestConsole e.g. (Google Chrome add-on)

Comment: Seams to work fine for me http://pastebin.com/71UxR4WM or do I misunderstand you what you mean by "all I get is values back"?.

Comment: yes seems to work now...although I got it working with JSONKit and the issue was the JSONKIt.m was not included in the 'Compile sources' section. Thanks for the help. How do I close this question?

Comment: Hmm so it was a compiltion error? You can answer your own question if you want or delete if dont think it can be usefull to others